# How to HttpContext User Identity ordering?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to support multiple authentication schemes - which I've got working successfully.

In my controller I want to track access to certain routes (logging the UserName of the user which I get from the claims from my auth schemes) by using `User.FindFirst(....)`. The ClaimsPrincipal interates through the claims by looking at the order of the ClaimsIdentity objects in the Identities property.

However, the second ClaimIdentity in that enumerable is the one I want the UserName value to come from if both ClaimIdentities are present.

Basically, I want to re-order ClaimIdentities in the ClaimPrincipal so I get the lookup precedence I want - I've added some middleware to do this.

*However*, even though I know this reordering works, when the logic eventually gets to my Controller code, the order is back to the original order. I've even tried removing one of the ClaimIdentities in my middleware, but when it gets to my controller both ClaimIdentities are back in the array.

Is it possible to do this?

```
public class IdentityOrderingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public IdentityOrderingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(context.User.Identities.OrderBy(i => i.AuthenticationType == "Cookies" ? 1 : 0));
        // context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(context.User.Identities.Where(i => i.AuthenticationType != "Cookies"));
        
        await _next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Is something re-creating the HttpContext.User (ClaimPrincipal) after my middleware? I've registered my middleware after `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Comment: If possible, you can try to achieve same by checking `User.Identity.AuthenticationType` and retrieve specific claim in controller action method.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did in the end - I want to check all the Identities in the array, but in an order. In a Lazy property in my base controller I now have an UserOrdered property that does `new Lazy<ClaimsPrincipal>(() => new ClaimsPrincipal(User.Identities.OrderBy(...)`. Doesn't feel like I've done this _correctly_, but I gave up. Unfortunately, this feels like typical MS frameworks - magic until you hit a problem, and then a lame hack when you encounter problems.